# Call for methods of an ArrayList in another class in Java

Tags: java, class, methods, arraylist, callback

If I have three classes. One class `A`, one class `Customer` where I've put an `ArrayList` of `A` in the constructor and one class `SavingsAccount` where I want to put them together. In class `A` I have a method which I want to call from `SavingsAccount`. How do I do that? And to call for both `Customer` and `SavingsAccount`?
In `Customer` there is a variable; `SocSecNr`, that has to match a `Nr` in `SavingsAccount`, to be correct in `A`, that's why I put an `ArrayList` of `SavingsAccount` in `Customer`.
(This is just an example class. I only want to know how to do this call without inheritance)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class A {
private ArrayList<Customer> customerlist;
private SavingsAccount account;

public A() {
    customerlist = new ArrayList<Customer>();
    account = new SavingsAccount();
}

public boolean deposit(long pNr, int accountId, double amount)
{   
    for(int i = 0; i < customerlist.size(); i++)
    {
        if(customerlist.get(i).getPCode() == pNr)
        {
            account.transaction(amount);
        }        
    }
    return false;        
       
}
public double transaction(){

    if(amount < 0 && balance + amount < 0)
        return -0;
    else
        return balance += amount;
}




   public class Customer {
private long pNr;
private ArrayList<SavingsAccount> accounts;

public Customer(long pCode)
{
    pNr = pCode;
    accounts = new ArrayList<SavingsAccount>();
}

public ArrayList<SavingsAccount> getAccount(){
    return accounts;
}
}



public class SavingsAccount {
private double balance;

public SavingsAccount(){
    accountId = accountCount;
}

public double transaction(double amount){
    if(amount < 0 && balance + amount < 0)
        return -0;
    else
        return balance += amount;

}
}
```

Comment: Classes and attributes are different things

Comment: You should start your class names with an uppercase letter, it makes the code easier to follow.

Comment: So, in A you have an ArrayList of B elements, or an ArrayList of some generic `type`? If so, why you called it b, as the name of the other class?

Comment: These are not my actual classes, just an example. I want to know the principle of how to enter the methods of c from class a. I have tried with c.callThisMethod(x) but only got error.

Comment: @Keppil I've improved my code so I hope it's easier to follow now.

Comment: @AntonioRagagnin Yes, in A it's an arraylist from the B class.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve it by two way

1- inheritance

```
class C extentds A{
 //all the public or protected attribues and methods are availble here 
}
```

2- By has a relationship.

```
class C{

   private A aType;

   aType.methode();
}
```

Comment: Your solution does not consider the ArrayList stuff.

Comment: you can say private List<A>  aList;

Answer (score 0):

*In class A I have a method which I want to call from C*

You should make an association between `A` and `C` via putting a `C` field into the `A`. You can pass the reference to it in the constructor or use a setter method to initialize it. Actually, you don't need them in the code for `deposit` method, but you can initialize them in this method for further references or usage in other methods.

**EDIT:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class A {
  private ArrayList<Customer> customerlist;
  private Customer customer;
  private SavingsAccount account;

  public A() {
      customerlist = new ArrayList<Customer>();
  }

  public boolean deposit(long pNr, int accountId, double amount)
  {   
      for(Customer customer : customerlist) {
          if(customer.getPCode() == pNr) {
            this.customer = customer; //initialize
            List<SavingsAccount> accounts = customer.getAccounts();
            for (SavingsAccount account : accounts) {
              if (account.getAccountId() == accountId){
                this.account = account; //initialize
                account.transaction(amount);
                return true;
              } 
            }
          }        
      }
      return false;            
  }

}

public class Customer {
  private long pNr;
  private ArrayList<SavingsAccount> accounts;

  public long getPCode(){
    return pNr;
  }

  public Customer(long pCode)
  {
    pNr = pCode;
    accounts = new ArrayList<SavingsAccount>();
  }

  public ArrayList<SavingsAccount> getAccounts(){
    return accounts;
  }
}



public class SavingsAccount {
  private double balance;
  private int accountId;

  public int getAccountId(){
    return accountId;
  }

  public SavingsAccount(int accountId){
    this.accountId = accountId;
  }

  public double transaction(double amount){
    if(amount < 0 && balance + amount < 0)
        return -0;
    else
        return balance += amount;

  }
}
```

Comment: Please see my updated code. Maybe I was unclear with the relations between the classes. I assume you mean to put an object of B and C in the A-class? Arraylist in A contains an object of B and arraylist in B contains an object of C

Comment: If arraylists have references then you could use them, otherwise you have to obtain them or create a new one.

Comment: I know the problem could be very simple, but I just don't know how to use them when they have a class between. How do i call the methods from C in A?

Comment: I don't think if I understand you correctly, but "in A" you should obtain a reference *value* to C. It's easy if you provide references as dependencies which you inject in to A when it's created. And, you can provide it later at the runtime. But I think you need not only a reference but an object inside the array which field should satisfy a search condition. Then you have search for B then in B search for C and return references of B and C that you could use to initialize A.

Comment: I put my methods in the code now and hope that will clear things up of what's (not) happening.

Comment: Well I think the code for `deposit` is it happening now?

Comment: I have changed the code again and I think it will work, but I have other problems to deal with in my methods... :-(

Comment: Updated the answer, I think it's clear how and why you should create class attributes.